# Unable to change iOS phone language with Appium Automation

Tags: ios, ui-automation, appium

I'm evaluating some tools for UI test automation for iOS. One of my key requirements is to be able to change the phone language. I'm currently looking at Appium. However, I can't seem to find a way to change the language of the physical phone or emulator.
Is there a way to do this with Appium?

Comment: A key requirement is to be able to change the language settings on the physical iPhone or simulator. Doesn't look like this can be done with Appium.

Comment: Do you want to change the language at the runtime or between separate launches?

Comment: Hi Nadarian, I'd like to run my tests on the physical phone, change the language setting, run the tests again, change language, and so on. What do you mean by seperate launches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, it's currently not possible to automate the iPhone settings app. Best to use the simulator instead where this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the server flag `--language en` when starting from console:
`node . --language en` or directly from the Appium GUI [image: Appium GUI]

Comment: Have you tried this yourself Nadarian on a physical iPhone? I was under the impression that it was very difficult to change physical iPhone settings such as language through automation.

Comment: I didn't run this on the device, but I assume that it should work. If not then you can try to simulate the home button and try to get to the settings menu but that would be quite inefficient

Comment: Nadarian, I confirmed that command only works on the Emulator/Simulator and not the physical device.